# soundcloud cross domains javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, soundcloud

I have problem to stream over soundcloud JavaScript API ONLY PART of the song to limit network traffic usage.

I've tried to make it over curl and thats working fine:

```
 curl -L -r 400-4000 "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/139272902/stream?client_id=7d2a254767bd1fededc0ff2867c94419"
```

but in javascript over browser I have problems with cross domain policy:

http://jsfiddle.net/SF5tX/10/

Anybody know how to stream over soundcloud part of the song using javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding #t=starttime(s),endtime(s):

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/139272902/stream?client_id=7d2a254767bd1fededc0ff2867c94419#t=50,60
```

This is a normal Webaudio feature, described here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Specifying_playback_range